# An example regarding proper mapping

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

> Suppose M is a manifold. $f=(f_1, f_2): M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. Give an example that $f$ is a proper mapping but neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ is.

> For Hausdorff space $X$ and $Y$, $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous. The mapping is proper means for every compact set $K\subset Y, f^{-1}(K)$ is compact in X.

I have learned that if $f_1$ is proper, then $f$ is also proper. The example asked in some sense tells us the reverse does not hold. Any ideas about how to construct the example?

Comment: Is that an exercise?

Comment: Yes, it is an exercise without answer or hint in my book.

Comment: Which book is it? Can you also include the page number?

Comment: Actually a notes written by a teacher in my school. Not published.

Comment: $\Bbb R\ni x\longmapsto (e^x,e^{-x})\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$.

Comment: The identity map on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.